# Defining string constants in configuration metadata

Tags: spring

I often have a need to define string constants in the XML configuration metadata file. These constants are things like Company Name, Fiscal Year, etc; that I need to lookup from various classes of my application. I end up coding them as bean definitions like `<bean id="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String" c:_0="Google" />`. Is there a better way to define this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can have your properties inside a property file for example.

config.properties

```
property1=value
property2=value
```

Then in your class you can use the propety file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class MyClass {

    @Value("${property1}")
    private String myProperty1;

    @Value("${property2}")
    private String myProperty2;
}
```

You can see these two tutorials

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Reos thanks for answering. I acknowledge that your suggestion is a valid alternative. But in my situation since I do not have any property files in my app, I am unwilling to create new one just for this purpose.

Comment: I also looked at the Spring boot external config URL. It does have good pointers that I will keep in mind to use in the future.